# Can't deploy Rails app RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, deployment

I am currently hosting my application and I keep getting this error when doing cap:deploy. cap deploy:check is ok.

I am not sure what this means and have tried everything suggested from stackoverflow questions to google and nothing has work.

```
     * executing "cat /var/www/lpacarnaval/current/REVISION"
    servers: ["x.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [x.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1152ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/lpacarnaval/releases/20131009165153; true"
    servers: ["x.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [x.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1218ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cat /var/www/lpacarnaval/current/REVISION'" on x.xx.xx.xxx
```

This is my deploy.rb

```
    load 'deploy/assets'
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :application, "lpacarnaval"
set :user, "administrador"  # The server's user for deploys
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/lpacarnaval"
set :rails_env, "production"
set :keep_releases, 5
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :rake, 'bundle exec rake'
set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.git"  # Your clone URL

set :branch, "master"
default_run_options[:pty] = true  # Must be set for the password prompt from git to work

role :web, "x.xx.xx.xxx"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "x.xx.xx.xxx"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "x.xx.xx.xxx", :primary => true        # This is where Rails migrations will run


task :bundle_install, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --without development test"
end

before "deploy:assets:precompile", :bundle_install

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_release} && bundle install --without development test"
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
  task :update_crontab, :roles => :db do
    run "cd #{release_path} && whenever --update-crontab #{application}"
  end

  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
      else
        logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
after "deploy:symlink", "deploy:update_crontab"
```

Comment: what user are you running this under? Are you positive that cap knows about $HOME correctly?

Comment: make sure that you have full read/write permissions of /var/www/lpacarnaval and all sub directories for that user. Could also be an issue with your repository as deploying fails when rolling out the new code. Make sure you don't have any merges in the works or conflicts on your master branch that need to be handled